# "Runtime Error '1004'" Command cannot be used on multiple selections

Tags: vba, excel

I put together a VBA code to take the values off a form on one worksheet and insert them into another worksheet without the blank cells inbetween, then clear the original form.

However, I run into the error "Runtime Error 1004: Command cannot be used on multiple selections" and cannot figure out what is causing it. After a little research, it seems that saving and reopening the workbook makes this error go away, but not always.

Any ideas?

```
Sub DataEntry()
'--- Find rows that contain any value in column G or H and copy them
Dim cell As Range
Dim selectRange As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("G3:H90")
    If (cell.Value <> "") Then
        If selectRange Is Nothing Then
            Set selectRange = cell
        Else
            Set selectRange = Union(cell, selectRange)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

selectRange.EntireRow.Select
selectRange.EntireRow.Copy

'Paste copied selection to the worksheet 'Data' on the next blank row
Sheets("Data").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial _
     Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Delete content of rows after copy and paste
Union(Range("G3:G150"), Range("H3:H150")).ClearContents
```

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: can you please post some sample data

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but "A65536" was the bottom cell of column A in Excel 2003. There are 1,048,576 rows these days.  Replace `Range("A65536")` by `Cells(Rows.Count,"A")` and it will work for any version of Excel.

Comment: Do you want to copy the `EntireRow` or just values found in columns `G:H`?

Comment: @SJR "selectRange.EntireRow.Copy" is the line that errors

Comment: @EEM I want to copy the entire row. Basically, I want the program to search for values in columns G:H. If a value is found in either column, I want it to copy and paste the entire row to another worksheet. That way I have a worksheet with just the rows containing data and no blank rows.

Comment: Funny, I can't replicate your error. Try commenting out the Select line so that you just have the Copy line (that's all you need). I wouldn't expect that to work but you never know!

Comment: @SJR That was the odd thing- the same error would come up with the same data and same code, but sporadically. I tried removing the select line and this seems to have worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. In general best to steer clear of Select anyway as very rarely is it needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `EntireRow` property is becoming a variant and not a range.  I initially tried to fix this by just declaring a variable as a Range, but this didn't work either.  However, by doing the original `Union` on rows instead of cells, I was able to get this to work.

```
Sub DataEntry()


'Find rows that contain any value in column G or H and copy them
Dim cell As Range
Dim selectRange As Range
Dim rowRange As Range

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("G3:H90")
    If (cell.Value <> "") Then
        If selectRange Is Nothing Then
            Set selectRange = cell.EntireRow
        Else
            Set selectRange = Union(cell.EntireRow, selectRange)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

'No need to select anything here, just copy.
selectRange.Copy
.....
```

I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, but this fixed it for me.

EDITED because the original fix did not work.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to have fixed it.